# Autoincrement inputname when element is cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
<div id="old">
   <input type="text" name="id"  id="id" size="2" value="1"/>
   <input type="text" name="UM"  id="UM" size="2"/>
   <input type="text" name="DS"  id="DS" size="2"/>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add" id="clone" />
<input type="button" value="remove" id="remove" />
```

with this Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input#clone").click(function(){
        $("div#old").clone().attr( 'id', 'new_div' ).appendTo("body")
        $("#id").val(parseInt($("#id").val()) + 1);

               $('#new_div input').each(function() {
               $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + 1);
               $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + 1);   
            });

              });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#remove").click(function(e) {

        if ($('#id').val() == '1')
        {
            $('remove').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else
        {
        $("#id").val(parseInt($("#id").val()) - 1);
        var $el = $('#new_div');
        $el.clone(true).appendTo('#new_div');
        $el.remove();
        }
    });
    });
```

But when I delete the cloned element deletes the first one no the last one.

Additional to this I want to autoincrement the name and the id of the inputs in cloned elements like:

1. iD1, UM1, DS1
2. iD2, UM2, DS2

**http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/aN37B/**

Thanks for all your help !

Comment: Call them by class and not ID. You cant have two elements with the same ID

Comment: That's not rendering valid HTML, IDs must be unique on document context, you are calling for trouble soon or later

Comment: Now the IDs auto increment with some number just like these: id1, id11, id111, but i want is to id1, id2, id3, I dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a solution without string parsing...

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aN37B/18/#update)

HTML:

```
<div id="old" class="old">
    <input type="text" name="id"  size="2" value="1"/>
    <input type="text" name="UM"  size="2"/>
    <input type="text" name="DS"   size="2"/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="clone" />
<input type="button" value="remove" id="remove" />
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 1;

$("input#clone").click(function(){
    //Let's make a copy to work with
    var originalDiv = $("div#old");
    var cloneDiv = originalDiv.clone(); 

    //Renaming cloneDiv
    cloneDiv.attr('id','newDiv'+counter);

    //Renaming inputs in  cloneDiv
    $("[name='id']",cloneDiv).attr('name','id'+counter);
    $("[name='UM']",cloneDiv).attr('name','UM'+counter);
    $("[name='DS']",cloneDiv).attr('name','DS'+counter); 

    //Value first textfield
    $("[name='id"+counter+"']",cloneDiv).val(1+counter); 

    //Append to originalDiv parent whatever it is...
    originalDiv.parent().append(cloneDiv);
    //OR Append it just after last created div
    //$('.old:last').after(cloneDiv);

    //Increment counter
    counter++;      
});

    $("input#remove").click(function(e) { 
        if(counter > 1){
            //Remove the last clone
            $('#newDiv'+(counter-1)).remove();
            //Decrease counter
            counter--;
        }         
    });  
});
```

Comment: Men, you're awesome !
Just one thing, is posible that this works like the original [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/aN37B/)? I mean : - Original - clone buttons - cloned elements ?
I think is in this line right ?
$('.old:last').after(cloneDiv);

Comment: Awesome men, I just change (+counter) instead (1+counter) because I will insert the cloned elements and no the original.

You're the best !

Comment: Help me men, I change an input for a select and clone the element but not the selected value, why ? Has the same name as input ? [Look](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/aN37B/)

Comment: In fact, you're not trying to change the select value, but you can do it easily, just be sure the value exists in the options values: [Look](http://jsfiddle.net/aN37B/25/)

Comment: Then I have to add that line for each option for each select ? I don't understand you, sorry. 
Can I use something like $("#optionid option:selected").text(); ?

[Look](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/aN37B/)

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you want... Sure you can, [Look](http://jsfiddle.net/aN37B/28/) . Don't forget you need JQuery 1.9+ to do it...

Comment: Sorry for not explain what I want in some way that you understand before, thanks again, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use class names to avoid using IDs on multiple elements or add some counter to your cloned element IDs.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#clone").click(function () {
        $("div#old").clone().attr('id', 'new_div').appendTo("body");

        //split by underscore of any input field within div to get counter
        var count = $('#new_div input:first-child').attr('id').split("_");
        count = count.pop();
        // set counter to 1 if its not already set or set it to +1 if its set
        count = count > 0 ? count + 1 : 1;

        //loop through all input elements and add counter to their IDs
        $('#new_div input').each(function() {
           $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_' + count);
           $(this).val($(this).val() + 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well I add some of your lines to mine and works I think but auto increment works so rare id1, id11, id111, can you modify to id1, id2, id3?